# Dask datframe comparing two column and assigning the result (True,False) to another column

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, dask, dask-dataframe

I know this type of question has been asked several times, but none of those solutions are helping me. So I am posting another one for my particular case.

I am getting data from SQL and the dataframe looks like :

```
#for getting data from server
df1 = dd.read_sql_table(sa_query, connect_str, index_col=ind_col, columns=sa_columns)

#df1
 col1 col2  ...  coln
    1       ...     1
    2       ...     3
  2.3       ...     3
    3       ...     4
```

and from a csv file using:

```
#for reading csv file
df2 = dd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False, dtype=str)

#df2
 col1  col2 ...  coln
    1       ...     1
    2       ...     2
  2.3       ...     3
    4       ...     4
```

I am merging the two dataframe and creating a new df that looks like:

```
#df
 col1_df1 col1_df2 col2_df1 col2_df2 ... coln_df1 coln_df2
        1        1                   ...        1        1
        2        2                   ...        3        2
      2.3      2.3                   ...        3        3
        3        4                   ...        4        4
```

I checked and all columns in df1 and df2 are of type `object` or `string` only. Some columns may contain null or no value in them. What I am trying to achieve is compare the values in `col1_df1` and `col2_df2` and create a new column `col1_match` with the True/False values from comparison.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to achieve this like :

```
if df[col1_df1].dtype.kind == df[col1_df2].dtype.kind:
    if df[col1_df1].dtype.kind == 'O':
        df[col1_match] = df[col1_df1].astype(str).fillna('') == df[col1_df2].astype(str).fillna('')
    elif df[col1_df1].dtype.kind == 'f':
        df[col1_match] = ((df[col1_df1] - df[col1_df2]).abs() <= 0)
    elif df[col1_df1].dtype.kind == 'i':
        df[col1_match] = ((df[col1_df1] - df[col1_df2]).abs() <= 0)
    else:
        df[col1_match] = df[col1_df1] == df[col1_df2]
else:
    print("does not match")
    df[col1_match] = df[col1_df1] == df[col1_df2]
```

This produces

```
col1_df1 col1_df2 col2_df1 col2_df2 ... coln_df1 coln_df2 col1_match col2_match ... coln_match
        1        1                  ...        1        1       True      False           True
        2        2                  ...        3        2       True      False          False
      2.3      2.3                  ...        3        3       True      False           True
        3        4                  ...        4        4      False      False           True
```

It is still returning `False` for null values.

Comment: What does "very close" mean for strings? You want to interpret as floats and compare those?

Comment: .02 difference does not matter. Its same for my case. But i am not able to convert string columns to float. I tried using `.astype(float)` but it gives me errors for that

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1.01,np.nan,np.nan], 'B':[1,1.02,np.nan,3]})
```

**Code:**

```
mask = (df['A'].astype(str) == df['B'].astype(str)) | ((df['A'] - df['B']).abs() <= 0.02)

df['col_1_match'] = mask
```

**Output:**

```
Out[13]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**Explaination:**

nan == nan is always false, but if you transform it to strings beforhand you can compare them, alternatively you could do a .fillna() with a defined value before comparing. As for the difference, just take value 1 mins value 2 and compare if the difference is smaller than your threshold.

Comment: nan == nan is always false. Thank you for explaining this. I am trying out your solution and see if it helps my case.

Comment: I am getting error `TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @bhakti123 this means you have some strings in you column, you can only calculate the difference betweent numbers not between strings. Thats why I calculate the difference based on the integer values and check if nan values are the same based on their string..

Comment: But if my columns contain "2.34" and "2.3" as strings, then how do I get True for this case?

Comment: try adding `.astype(int)` or `.map(int)`

Comment: I tried with `.astype(float)` but i get error `Cannot convert string to float`

Comment: then you have propably a string there whhich isn't a string representation of a number like: `2.01 ` or ` 2.01` or 'nan'. You have to handle them before you can move on.

Comment: How do i check? and how do i handle those?

Comment: I checked the dtypes of all columns and it prints `object` for all of them.

Comment: Try to find out which calue makes problems, first load the first half of df1 and try, then only the second. If the error is only in the first half, then half it again and so on until you know whats the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I was able to solve it like:

```
#for getting data from server
df1 = dd.read_sql_table(sa_query, connect_str, index_col=ind_col, columns=sa_columns)

#for reading csv file
df2 = dd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False, dtype=str)

#merging the data frames
params = {"on": join_columns}
outer_join = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", suffixes=("_df1", "_df2"), indicator=True, **params)
intersect_rows = outer_join[outer_join["_merge"] == "both"].copy()

#for getting True/False
for column in sorted(set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns)):    
    intersect_rows = intersect_rows.map_partitions(map_compare, column)

def map_compare(df, column):
    try:
        df[column + "_match"] = np.isclose(df[column + "_df1"], df[column + "_df2"], rtol=0.005, atol=0.005, equal_nan=True)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            df[column + "_match"] = np.isclose(df[column + "_df1"].astype(float), df[column + "_df2"].astype(float), rtol=0.005, atol=0.005, equal_nan=True)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            try:
                df[column + "_match"] = (df[column + "_df1"] == df[column + "_df2"]) | (df[column + "_df1"].isnull() & df[column + "_df2"].isnull())
            except:
                df[column + "_match"] = np.equal(df[column + "_df1"].astype(str), df[column + "_df2"].astype(str))
    return df
```